# Unix command to create NEXT file name.

Tags: unix

On unix, I have a list of CSV files that were randomly created during different time period, and all files are of the same name format, such as:

```
"NYC_2014-04-29-001.csv, 
NYC_2014-04-30-001.csv, 
NYC_2014-04-30-002.csv, 
...
NYC_2014-05-01-001.csv,".
```

Is there a command for me to `create` the `NEXT` csv file name, basing on current time stamp ?
For example, for the above list, I am looking for something as `"NYC_2014-05-01-002.csv"`.

Thanks,
John

Comment: What's the pattern? Are there always two files for every date, `NYC_YYYY-MM-DD-001.csv` and `NYC_YYYY-MM-DD-002.csv`, and no `...-003.csv`?

Answer (score 0):

One-liner using `bash` (assuming your list of names is in **listfile**):

`echo "NYC_$(date +%Y-%m-%d)-$(printf "%03d" $(($(grep -c $(date +%Y-%m-%d) listfile) + 1))).csv,"`

To avoid multiple calls to `date`, we can break the thing up into multiple lines:

Get the current timestamp formatted to YYYY-MM-DD:

```
cur_date=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
```

Count the number of files with the current timestamp already in file (again, assuming the list is in **listfile**:

```
count=$(grep -c ${cur_date} listfile)
```

Print the next file name, which will be the current date with the count + 1 appended, which we will pad with zeros to be three characters long:

```
echo "NYC_${cur_date}-$(printf "%03d" $((${count} + 1))).csv,"
```

You can update your **listfile** by redirecting the final command using `>> listfile`